# why the mp3 did not contains any meta data when read using python eyed3

Tags: python-3.x, mp3

I get a mp3 file, the file name is UUID so I want to found the file name from the MP3 file meta data like this using Python:

```
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "./demo.mp3")
        tag = eyed3.load("./demo.mp3")
        print(tag.tag.artist)
        print(tag.tag.title)
```

but the title and artist output was None!!! why the mp3 file did not contains meta data? if did not contains the meta data, how to know the mp3 songs information? if did not have a meta data, I think nobody knows what is the songs information if they did not know the songs before. Or I read the meta information the wrong way?

Comment: It is likely that there is not metadata in the file. Have you tried opening with a mp3 tag editor? You can also open it on any mp3 player and if it has title and tags it will show it. The code seems fine.

Comment: If there is **no metadata** in the MP3 then you **cannot read** it. If you want to you can add it yourself to the file by using a `mp3 tag editor` search for a free one online (for your operating system _ie:_ Windows or Mac?).

Comment: I am using centos operation system. @VC.One

Comment: You can try an [online MP3 tag editor](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+mp3+tag+editor), like this one: [tagmp3.net](https://tagmp3.net/).